Use m4 interactively with bc
I would like to use m4 interactively as a preprocessor for bc. My immediate use case is to add an include capability to bc, but I can foresee other uses in the future. But there is a problem. Here is an example using bc on its own:
$ bc
bc 1.07.1
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2012-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
3+7
10
sqrt(12345)
111
quit
$

And here is the same example using m4 interactively:
$ m4 -iP - | bc
3+7
10
sqrt(12345)
111
quit

$

There are two differences. First, the m4 version suppresses the banner. Second, the m4 version doesn't execute quit immediately, but instead requires the enter key to be pressed an additional time before it executes the quit.
Why do these things occur? How can I make the m4 version work the same way as the bc version?

Why can you not use eval See Section 3.5 of the m4 manual

@eyoung100: Because eval in m4 does not provide the arbitrary-precision arithmetic that bc does.

Is the observed behavior here really specific to m4? don't you get the same with any piped input e.g. cat | bc?

@steeldriver: Good point. Yes, the observed behavior is the same. But I want to use m4 interactively with bc (hence the -i flag on m4), and cat has no utility if used interactively, for instance cat - } bc.

I assume bc only outputs the version and license information when its input is connected to a terminal. You would not want that stuff every time you used it in a script (or in this case, through a pipe).

@Paul_Pedant: Good point. I always added the -q flag in that case, but it looks like that's not necessary. So that answers the first question. Thank you. There is still the question of why quit doesn't work immediately.

quit means nothing to m4 -- it is merely passed to bc. bc exits as required. But m4 still has a writable end of a pipe. It only finds out bc is gone when it writes to the pipe again, and gets SigPipe. If you Ctrl-D (EOF) to m4, it closes both processes immediately.

@Paul_Pedant: Ah, that explains it. Thank you. And that means there is no way to make the m4 version work exactly the same was as the native bc version.\

@user448810  I don't have any knowledge of m4, apart from "macro processor". But it seems to me that it should be possible to have the quit make m4 itself exit, which would pipe EOF to bc to close that too. You could possibly also fool bc into showing its version using timeout 0.25 bc before starting m4, as bc would then be (briefly) attached to the terminal. A short wrapper script for m4 would be able to fix both your issues.

@Paul_Pedant: I added an m4 macro to define quit as m4exit, that was easy, and it now works fine. But there is a new problem. I lose the ability to use the readline functionality of bc because it is m4 reading the keyboard, so I call the program under control of rlwrap: rlwrap m4 -iP quit - | bc. That works, sorta kinda, bc produces correct output, readline functionality and the quit macro work, but the problem is that the output from bc is written on the line above the input. I tried all the different flags to rlwrap but none fix the problem. This is hard!

It seems to be working properly when I execute the m4|bc pipeline as a subshell in the rlwrap command: rlwrap -aN sh -c "m4 -iP quit - | bc". I'm still experimenting, not yet ready to declare victory.

I found you can tell bc to behave as if it had a terminal, and to do nothing except output the version etc. bc -i </dev/null before you start the pipeline. Sorry I don't have rlwrap so cannot work on that.

@Paul_Pedant: Thanks for your help!

Here is what I came up with, which seems to be working the way I expect, though I am still experimenting. The bc shell script is in /usr/local/bin/bc which is on the $PATH prior to /usr/bin/bc:
#! /bin/sh

HELP="usage: /usr/local/bin/bc [options] [file ...]
  -h              print usage message and exit
  -s              synclines; same as m4 -s
  -v              print bc version information and exit
  -D name[=value] define macro name, optionally give it a value
  -I directory    location of m4 include directory
  -U name         undefine macro name
  NOTE: bc -ql are always active; bc -sw are unavailable;
        m4 -P is always active; m4 -i may be active"

USAGE="-[hsv] [-D name[=value]] [-I directory] [-U name]\n"

# file locations
BC=/usr/bin/bc
BCPRE=/usr/local/bin/bc.prelude
M4=/usr/bin/m4
M4PRE=/usr/local/bin/bc.m4.prelude
SCRIPT="./bc.script.$(date +%Y%m%d)"

# collect command options
M4OPTS=""
while getopts "hsvD:I:U:" flag
do  case $flag in
    h) echo "$HELP"; exit 0;;        # print help message and exit
    s) M4OPTS="$M4OPTS -s";;         # synclines
    v) $BC -v; exit 0;;              # print bc version and exit
    D) M4OPTS="$M4OPTS -D $OPTARG";; # define macro name[=value]
    I) M4OPTS="$M4OPTS -I $OPTARG";; # specify include directory
    U) M4OPTS="$M4OPTS -U $OPTARG";; # undefine macro name
    ?) echo "Usage: $0 $USAGE"; exit 2;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# initialize random number generator
SRAND=$(mktemp /tmp/bc.srand.XXXXXX)
echo "srand = $(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom)" > $SRAND
trap "rm -f $SRAND" 0 1 2 3 15

# execute bc
if   test -t 0
then script -qfa bc.script.$(date +%Y%m%d) -c \
     "rlwrap -aN sh -c \"$M4 -iP $M4PRE $SRAND $BCPRE $@ - | $BC -ql\""
else $M4 -P $M4PRE $SRAND $BCPRE $@ - | $BC -ql
fi

Here is bc.prelude:
scale = 0; ibase = obase = A

define int(x) { # truncate toward zero
    auto s; s = scale; scale = 0; x /= 1; scale = s; return x }
define frac(x) { return x - int(x) }
define abs(x) { if (x<0) return -x else return x }
define sgn(x) { if (x<0) return -1; if (x>0) return 1; return 0 }
define max(a,b) { if (a<b) return b else return a }
define min(a,b) { if (a<b) return a else return b }
define mod(n,m) {
    auto x, s; s = scale; scale = 0; x = n % m; scale = s
    if (x < 0) return x + m; return x }
define gcd(a,b) {
    auto x, s; s = scale; scale = 0
    while (b != 0) { x = mod(a,b); a = b; b = x }
    scale = s; return a }
define push(*stack[],value) { return(stack[++stack[0]]=value) }
define pop(*stack[]) {
    if (stack[0]<1) stack[-1] else return stack[stack[0]--] }

define srand(seed) { # seed on half-open range [0,2^32)
    auto i, old_scale; old_scale = scale; scale = 0; srand[0] = seed
    for (i=1; i<32; i++) # initialize shuffle box
        srand = srand[i] = (69069 * srand[i-1] + 1234567) % 4294967296
    scale = old_scale; return seed }
junk = srand(srand) # initial seed from /dev/urandom via bc shell script
define rand() { # pseudorandom integer on half-open range [0,2^32)
    auto j, n, old_scale; old_scale = scale; scale = 0
    srand = (69069 * srand + 1234567) % 4294967296
    n = srand[(j = 32 * srand / 4294967296)]
    srand[j] = srand; scale = old_scale; return n }
define randint(lo,hi) { # pseudorandom integer from lo to hi inclusive
    auto randint, old_scale; old_scale = scale; scale = 0
    randint = (hi - lo + 1) * rand() / 4294967296 + lo
    scale = old_scale; return randint }

And here is bc.m4.prelude:
m4_divert(-1)

m4_define(error, `{ print $1, "\n"; 0/0 }')

m4_define(with_scale,
    { junk = push(saved_scale[],scale); scale = $1;
    $2;
    scale = pop(saved_scale[]) })

m4_define(load, `m4_include($1)')

m4_define(quit, `m4_m4exit')

m4_divert`'m4_dnl

Here is a sample interaction with bc:
$ bc
rand()
2525043732
with_scale(20,a(1)*4)
3.14159265358979323844
define fib(n) {
    auto f1, f2, f3
    f1 = 0; f2 = 1
    while (n-- > 0) {
        f3 = f1 + f2
        f1 = f2; f2 = f3 }
    return f2 }
fib(37)
39088169
quit
$

The readline command history seems to work properly, and I expect that automatically collecting a transcript (one file per day, with multiple bc sessions in the same file) will be extremely useful (how did I define that function the other day?).
All of these will doubtless change with time, but at least I have a start.
